# How to calculate theoretical value of mass output using electrolysis with different electrolyte concentrations?

Tags: concentration, theoretical-chemistry, electrolysis

I am writing a research paper on a zinc-copper electrolysis experiment observing the mass output of Zinc on a copper cathode, in which I am changing the concentration of the zincsulfate electrolytic solution in each trial.During the experiment, the controlled variables were duration of electrolysis and current. This experiment resulted in a positive correlation between mass output and the increase in electrolyte concentration. Now I am trying to calculate the theoretical mass output with the use of different concentrtions of electrolyte, but it doesn't seem possible using Faraday's laws. How can I calculate the theoretical value?

Comment: More diluted solution = more negative cathode potential = faster parallel reduction of hydronium = lower zinc mass for given charge.

Comment: Why is it not possible to use Faraday's laws? Nobody has ever thought that they are unusable.

Comment: @Maurice OP probably means it is not directly applicable if the same total charge leads to different masses of the product of the particular redox reaction. (as part of the charge is spent on a parallel reaction)